# Javascript / lodash filtering an array very slow

Tags: javascript, regex, lodash

I've got a large array of objects.  I'm creating a second array based on filtering the first array by one of the properties of that object.  My code is...

```
let re = RegExp("^" + term, "i");
this.filteredList = _.filter(this.list, item => item.value.search(re) > -1);
```

Oh... I'm using lodash at the moment but the native Javascript filter was being just as slow. Is there a more efficient way to filter the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to be the contrarian here and say that you're not going to do better than a regular expression here, and I have the benchmarks to back it up.

I'm not going to talk about lodash, lodash isn't doing anything that will change the performance characteristics much.

### TL;DR

You can eke out a little more performance by swapping out `item.value.search(re) > -1` for `re.test(item.value)`. You get the same result, but with a little less work. With that (and without lodash), your code looks like this:

```
let re = RegExp('^' + term, 'i');
this.filteredList = this.list.filter(item => re.test(item.value));
```

...and that's about the best you'll do.

### The benchmarks

I tried four different methods:

1. **toLowerCase().startsWith**, i.e. [acontell's (original) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48955326/179125):

   ```
   var termLower = term.toLowerCase();
   var filteredList = list.filter(
     item => item.toLowerCase().startsWith(termLower));
   ```
2. **slice().toLowerCase equality**, i.e. [trincot's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954988/179125):

   ```
   var termLower = term.toLowerCase();
   var filteredList = list.filter(
     item => item.substr(0, termLower.length).toLowerCase() === termLower);
   ```
3. **RegExp#test** (the winner):

   ```
   var expr = new RegExp('^' + term, 'i');
   var filteredList = list.filter(item => expr.test(item));
   ```
4. **String#search** (your original solution):

   ```
   var expr = new RegExp('^' + term, 'i');
   var filteredList = list.filter(item => item.search(expr));
   ```

You can see my benchmarks here: https://jsperf.com/array-of-strings-prefix-search#10. Note the `#10` at the end of the URL. Change the number to change the length of the strings (in words) in `list`. The setup code builds an array (`searchSpace`) of 100 sentences of the given length and an array of 100 search prefixes.

I ran the benchmark for sentence lengths from 1 to 500 in Chrome 64 (macOS 10.12). Here are the results:

[image: prefix search benchmark results]

Unsurprisingly, **toLowerCase().startsWith** gets asymptotically worse the longer the sentences get, since it has to lowercase the whole sentence each time.

Likewise **slice().toLowerCase equality** stays the same after its drop between 1 and 2, since it's lowercasing just one word no matter what.

And then there's `RegExp#test` and `String#search`, which do basically the same thing except for the small amount of extra work for the latter. Modern JavaScript engines are very good at compiling regular expressions, especially very simple ones like `/^keyword/`. In the end, searching with a regular expression is much faster, since we don't have to do any lowercasing or slicing.

### Postscript

Every benchmark is limited, and it's also entirely possible mine is flawed in some significant way. I'll be happy to hear any thoughts on how to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

The slow down is most certainly caused by the regular expression. Try without it:

```
const termL = term.toLowerCase();
this.filteredList = this.list.filter(
    item => item.substr(0, termL.length).toLowerCase() === termL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is checking if the string starts with the term (case insensitive), you can use lodash `_.startsWith` and avoid the regexp.

Even though the benchmarking is not perfect, it can give you some insight of the performance of some answers.

```js
const list = [...Array(10000).keys()].map(n => 'asdfAasdfaSSSddd');
const term = 'd';

console.time('original');
let re = RegExp("^" + term, "i");
_.filter(list, item => item.search(re) > -1);
console.timeEnd('original');

console.time('one solution with lodash');
let termLowerCase = term.toLowerCase();
_.filter(list, item => item[0].toLowerCase() === term);
console.timeEnd('one solution with lodash');

console.time('another solution with lodash');
let termLowerCase1 = term.toLowerCase();
_.filter(list, item => _.startsWith(item.toLowerCase(), termLowerCase1));
console.timeEnd('another solution with lodash');

console.time('trinkots solution');
const termL = term.toLowerCase();
list.filter(
    item => item.substr(0, termL.length).toLowerCase() === termL
);
console.timeEnd('trinkots solution');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you benchmark this? Its performance seems highly dependent on the length of the strings in `this.list`. `toLowerCase()` isn't free.

Comment: you're right, I should've avoided saying "which indeed is slower" without benchmarking. I just wanted to provide the "lodash" version. I'm going to correct that part. Thanks!

Comment: @JordanRunning I've added some benchmarking though from my point of view, it should be tested in the environment in which the script is going to be run (browser, node) and with a better tool...